# Взаимодействие потоков и их синхронизация

Tags: java, многопоточность, synchronized

Есть два потока.

1) *Выполняет считывание символов из файла*

2) *Проверяет является ли символ числом, если нет кидает эксепшен*

Не могу понять каким образом сделать так что бы гарантированно первым запускался поток считывания из файла и не могу сообразить какое условие задать в цикле второго потока, что бы он завершался вместе с первым если символы в файле закончились. Заранее спасибо за любую помощь.

```
public class MultiThread {
private static Object monitor = new Object();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ReadFromFile readFromFile = new ReadFromFile("MultiThreaded\\MultithreadingMatrix\\matrixA.txt");
    Thread readFromFileThread = new Thread(readFromFile);
    Thread validationThread = new Thread(new Validation());
    try {
        readFromFileThread.start();
        validationThread.start();

        readFromFileThread.join();
        validationThread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static class ReadFromFile implements Runnable {
    private String path;
    private StringBuilder matrix;
    private static Character character;

    public ReadFromFile(String path) {
        this.path = path;
        this.matrix = new StringBuilder();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(" Read from file start ");
        try (InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(path))) {
            while (isr.ready()) {
                synchronized (monitor) {
                    character = (char) isr.read();
                    matrix.append(character);
                    monitor.notify();
                    monitor.wait();
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(" Read from file end ");
    }
}

private static class Validation implements Runnable {
    private Character currentChar;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(" Validation start ");
        try {
            while (true) {
                synchronized (monitor) {
                    currentChar = ReadFromFile.character;
                    if (currentChar != null) {
                        if (currentChar != ' ' && currentChar != '\n' && currentChar != '\r'
                                && currentChar != '-') {
                            if (!Character.isDigit(currentChar)) {
                                throw new ValidationException();
                            } else {
                                System.out.println(currentChar + " число");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    monitor.notify();
                    monitor.wait();

                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException | ValidationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(" Validation end ");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Создавайте второй поток внутри `run` первого потока

Comment: @iksuy Спасибо, сработало если ещё сделать второй поток demon то он и закрывается вместе с тем потоком который его запускает. Только не уверен, что это красиво и безопасно )

Comment: Если вы нашли решение своей проблемы, то неплохо бы его более-менее развернуто описать в виде ответа :)

Comment: @m.vokhm ok. Ниже развёрнутый ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Спасибо **@iksuy** за по сути ответ в коментарии. Создаём второй поток внутри `run` первого потока.

```
public class MatrixMultiThread {
private static final Object monitor = new Object();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ReadFromFile readFromFile = new ReadFromFile("MultiThreaded\\MultithreadingMatrix\\matrixA.txt");
    Thread readFromFileThread = new Thread(readFromFile);
    try {
        readFromFileThread.start();
        readFromFileThread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static class ReadFromFile implements Runnable {
    private String path;
    private StringBuilder matrix;
    private static Character character;
    private Thread validationThread;

    public ReadFromFile(String path) {
        this.path = path;
        this.matrix = new StringBuilder();
        this.validationThread = new Thread(new Validation());
    }

    public StringBuilder getMatrix() {
        return matrix;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        validationThread.setDaemon(true);
        validationThread.start();
        try (InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(path))) {
            while (isr.ready()) {
                synchronized (monitor) {
                    character = (char) isr.read();
                    matrix.append(character);
                    monitor.notify();
                    monitor.wait();
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private static class Validation implements Runnable {
    private Character currentChar;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                synchronized (monitor) {
                    currentChar = ReadFromFile.character;
                    if (currentChar != null) {
                        if (currentChar != ' ' && currentChar != '\n' && currentChar != '\r'
                                && currentChar != '-') {
                            if (!Character.isDigit(currentChar)) {
                                throw new ValidationException();
                            } else {
                                System.out.println(currentChar + " число");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    monitor.notify();
                    monitor.wait();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException | ValidationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```